# Camunda A/B Testing

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

Anybody has experience with A/B testing in Camunda. For Example, if I have two external tasks, which ties to a front screen say built in React. How do we make Camunda go to one external task 80% of the time vs 20% of the time to other one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Untested: Assuming you are using spring/boot you can use an expression in the "topic" field of the external task property in your bpmn.
That expression then could dynamically define the topic to be used.

[image: random topic]

Now `randomTopicGenerator` could be a bean which `rollDice()` method returns topic name `topic-name-v1` and `topic-name-v2` by using an 80/20 random function.

You than start two external-task-workers, one for each topic.

When you make the topic-name structure and the ratio configurable, you can later disable the old topic.